# Replace two buttons with a toggle switch

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement, toggle

I have the following code:

```
<img id="v1" src="pic1.jpg"><br>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('v1').src='pic1.jpg'">Before</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('v1').src='pic2.jpg'">After</button>
<br>
<img id="v2" src="pic3.jpg"><br>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('v2').src='pic3.jpg'">Before</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('v2').src='pic4.jpg'">After</button>
<br>
```

However, I would like to replace these 'Before' and 'After' buttons with a toggle switch (already made) in the form of a checkbox:

```
<label class="switchBA">
<input type="checkbox" checked>
<span class="slider"></span>
</label>
```

In a way that each time it's clicked it switches between the two functions. I guess this needs to be done inline since these are just two of many comparisons.

Thanks in advance.

P.S: I would like to do with only with JS. No need for jQuery or other frameworks.

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you have a specific problem you're asking us to help with, or are you asking us to write code for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a nice way to achieve this by listening for the toggle in javascript and setting the image to that of the custom data attribute set under the image tag.

```js
var toggleClass = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle");

var toggleFunction = function() {
  var imageElement = this.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("imageItem")[0];
  if(this.checked){
    imageElement.src = imageElement.getAttribute("data-image-2");
  }else{
    imageElement.src = imageElement.getAttribute("data-image-1");
  }
};

for (var i = 0; i < toggleClass.length; i++) {
    toggleClass[i].addEventListener('click', toggleFunction, false);
}
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

```html
<h2>Toggle Image Demo</h2>
<div class="imageContainer">
  <img class="imageItem" src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/5/Image1/" data-image-1="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/5/Image1/" data-image-2="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/6/Image2/">

  <label class="switch">
    <input class="toggle" type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider"></span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="imageContainer">
  <img class="imageItem" src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/5/Image1/" data-image-1="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/5/Image1/" data-image-2="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/6/Image2/">

  <label class="switch">
    <input class="toggle" type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Taking this approach over CSS and Backgrounds or setting the second image URL in the javascript should help keep the code cleaner. Also by doing this, the code will be easier to scale to accommodate multiple images toggles on one page without changing the Javascript.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The data attributes are a nice solution. That does solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
function toggleImage(){
 var el = document.getElementById("toggle")
 if(el.checked){
 document.getElementById("v1").src="https://picsee.co/images/social_facebook.png";
 }
 else{
  document.getElementById("v1").src="https://picsee.co/images/social_twitter.png";
 }
}
```

```html
<img id="v1" src="https://picsee.co/images/social_facebook.png">

<label class="switchBA">
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle" checked onclick="toggleImage()">
<span class="slider"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. That does what I want, however the problem is that toggle function is tied to one 'id' and I have over 30 individual comparisons. Do you think there is a more efficient way?

Comment: you mean 30 checkboxes ?

Comment: Yes. But someone already suggested using attributes for each element, which ends up being a bit easier.

Comment: @jedi_coder yeah, I see that. you can still give it an upvote at least ;)

Comment: Oh, I would, but don't have enough reputation yet. As soon as I get it, I'll do it.

EDIT: Done. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onchange` event to get the event on state change as below

```js
function oncheckchange(e)
{
console.log(event.currentTarget.checked)
if(event.currentTarget.checked)
  document.getElementById('v2').src='pic4.jpg'
else 
  document.getElementById('v2').src='pic3.jpg'
}
```

```html
<img id="v1" src="pic1.jpg"><br>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('v1').src='pic1.jpg'">Before</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('v1').src='pic2.jpg'">After</button>
<br>
<img id="v2" src="pic3.jpg"><br>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('v2').src='pic3.jpg'">Before</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('v2').src='pic4.jpg'">After</button>
<br>

<label class="switchBA">
<input type="checkbox" checked onchange="oncheckchange()">
<span class="slider"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should never execute code in a handler the way you do. It's doable but in terms of readibility and maintainability it sucks, the handlers should only be used to fire a function.

It's fairly simple to achieve what you want.
put the toggle code inside a div and put the image and the newly created div inside a container div.
The div holding the toggle should include "display:none" in the css from the beginning so it is not shown, once you click on the button, you just need to hide the image and show the toggle switch div by changing "display:none" to "display:block";
Something like

```
<div class="container">
        <img id="image1"src="https://openclipart.org/download/216413/coniglio_rabbit_small.svg" alt="">
        <div id="toggle">
          <img id="image2"src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/256/sign-check-icon.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <button onclick="Change()">Click me</button>
      </div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rYGMYx

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to set the image as the background image of an element and then toggle that CSS setting by toggling the class that defines it:

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.querySelector(".slider").classList.toggle("otherImage");
});
```

```css
div {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background-size:contain;
  border:1px solid black;
}

/* This will be the default style used because the class is defined in the HTML */
.slider {
  background-image:url("http://aws-cdn-01.shemazing.ie/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/disappointed-but-relieved-face.png");
}


/* This will be toggled on and off by the clicking of the checkbox. When it is 
   toggled on, it will override the previous background-image value. */
.otherImage {
  background-image:url("https://au.res.keymedia.com/files/image/emoji.jpg");
}
```

```html
<label class="switchBA">
<input type="checkbox" checked>
<div class="slider"></div>
</label>
```